# Secondary Db Context in ASP.NET CORE EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a service that sends notifications, it requires a db connection to lookup subscriptions. I also have a controller (and may more) that does some logic, and sends notifications.

The problem with this is, because of [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) it uses the same instance of the `DbContext` so I get a error thrown for re-using a `DataReader` in the same context (understandable).

I would really love to do this without enabling the MARS flag in `DbConnectionString`. Given that the controllers cannot use `.ToList()` or no tracking and the 'inner' `NotificationService` needs to lookup the database - is this even possible?

```
public class NotificationSystem
{
     private readonly DbContext context;
     public NotificationSystem(DbContext context) { this.context = context;}

     public void SendNotification(string username){
       var subscriptions = context.subscriptions.where(u => u.username == username); 
       // Do some notification stuff
     } 
}
```

And a simple controller

```
public class SendRemindersController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly NotificationSystem _notificationSystem;

    public SendRemindersController(DbContext context, NotificationSystem notificationSystem)
    {
        this._context = context;
        this._notificationSystem = notificationSystem;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var reminders = _context.Reminders.Where(r => r.Sent == false && r.RemindAt < DateTime.UtcNow);

        foreach (var reminder in reminders)
        {
            await _notificationSystem.SendNotificationToUser(reminder.UserId);
            reminder.Sent = true;
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

And `startup.cs` (yes I know I haven't used an interface, that will get refactored later).

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
services.AddTransient<NotificationSystem, NotificationSystem>();
```

### Update

This question is flawed since i was under the false impression that .ToList/.ToArray also detached the entities from the context. In-fact these do not detach and only execute the query.

Comment: This error would appear if you use lazy initialization for a `reminder` field, or if `SendNotificationToUser` is trying to execute a query in the middle of the iteration. Make sure you load all required data when the operation starts, eg by using an `Include()` statement.

Comment: BTW you should have a *relation* from reminder to User or Subscription, not use an ID like the username to link them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in real code there is :) I'm just trying to give an example.

Comment: In this case you wouldn't need a second query. You could walk the relations. In any case, you should try to load all the data you need at the start, to avoid both this error and multiple roundtrips to the database

Comment: The code I used above is a modified code, the 'real' notification code needs to scan up and down the user tree for 'related' users in a hierarchy so 'parent' users can also be notified. I just simplified it for the purposes of this example.

Comment: That's a job for the database and eg `hierarchyid`. Finding parents of a node is trivial this way. EF does support hierarchyid through [an extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId). This will increase your performance 100x at least (1 query for all parents instead of 3-4 recursions per item)

Comment: Yup already got that part covered - I use a lineage system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using the same `DbContext` to execute multiple simultaneous transactions. If you add `.ToListAsync()` to this line of code like this

```
var reminders = await _context.Reminders
  .Where(r => r.Sent == false && r.RemindAt < DateTime.UtcNow)
  .ToListAsync();
```

It will retrieve all the reminders immediately and then the code inside the loop (after this statement) can use the `DbContext` without the `DbContext` throwing an exception because an active result set is still being iterated over.

Comment: I understand that but I cannot use a .ToList or a Without tracking ("Given that the controllers cannot use .ToList() or no tracking and the 'inner' NotificationService needs to lookup the database - is this even possible?") because some controllers that use the service will need to update their entities.

Comment: @JohnMitchell - ToList and AsNoTracking are 2 unrelated things. You can use ToList in this instance and still be able to update the entities in the same manner as normal.

Comment: @JohnMitchell why *can't* you use that? You are doing this already, without realizing it, *and* in the slowest way possible (ie synchronously). You are probably trying to lazily load data too, resulting in the N+1 query problem. The fix is to load all necessary data in the beginning (the lookups too). This will result in *faster* execution because you make only 1 call instead of N

Comment: Maybe I'm mis-understanding ToList - I thought this would `detach` the resultant entities?

Comment: @JohnMitchell no, it won't. It will *execute* the query and return the results in an IList. I'd prefer `ToArrayAsync` though, if you don't intend to add new items to the list

Comment: Awesome - updated original question to reflect that.

Comment: @JohnMitchell - good deal. Should you ever want to retrieve detached entities there is a named extension called `.AsNoTracking()` that would do that. AFAIK there are no other native extension methods that would implicitly do this.